# How to access Operations and Attributes of a State Machine diagram element in Enterprise Architect using C#

Tags: c#, add-in, enterprise-architect

I need to fetch the attributes and operations of diagram objects of a state machine diagram using C#. But I am not able to find those things neither inside the diagram nor inside the element itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get details of attributes and operation you need to loop through Attributes and Methods collection of element .

For Attributes :

```
            foreach (EA.Attribute att in currentElement.Attributes)
            {
            }
```

For Operations:

```
            foreach (EA.Method att in currentElement.Methods)
            {
            }
```

Please refer [Attributes](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/attribute.html) and [Operations](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/method.html) for more deials